# Will all cages in a jail be used?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I currently have a jail with individual "rooms" (no doors leading out, more like individual alcoves) containing cages and chains. I made a room with one of the cages, indicating the whole area as being a jail (and used for justice).

Will all the other cages in that designed room be used as jail cells, or only the one I specifically indicated to be so? What about the chains in that same area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the cages in the room will be used, as long as they are marked for justice use.